# Get list of subdirectories of specified PATH to specified number of child directories

Tags: php, directory

I am using this code to get list of sub directories.

```
<?php
$path = '/www/sites/';

$directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME);

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);

foreach ($iterator as $file => $info) {
    if ($info->isDir()) {
        echo $file . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

But it is returning me something like this

```
/www/sites/000/4e7
/www/sites/000/4e7/.
/www/sites/000/4e7/..
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/.
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/..
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web/.
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web/..
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web/cgi-bin
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web/cgi-bin/.
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web/cgi-bin/..
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web/Resources
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com/web/Resources/.
```

I specified root path as `/www/sites`
What I only need in the above output is

```
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com
```

Rest are useless to me. It means I only want to crawl up to 3 sub directories from specified path. I have thousands of thousands of sub directories that's why I want to modify current code as it is taking too much time
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [directoryiterator::isdot()](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php), [recursiveiteratoriterator::getdepth()](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getdepth.php), eg:

```
<?php
$path = '/www/sites/';

$directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME);

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator,RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);

foreach ($iterator as $file => $info) {
    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // Restrict to 3 levels only and ignore non-directory and dot files 
    if ($info->getDepth() >= 3 || !$info->isDir() || $info->isDot())
        continue;
    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    echo $file . "\n";
}
```

Output

```
/www/sites/000
/www/sites/000/4e7
/www/sites/000/4e7/mydomains.com
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::getDepth() in /www/sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php on line 11

Comment: I just pasted your code and giving me this error, I tested on live server and localhost, same error on both places :(

Comment: really weird error... Searching, google does not find anything https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Call+to+undefined+method+SplFileInfo%3A%3AgetDepth%28%29%22

Comment: I just asked you after finding nothing from google :(